# Returning related data records in yii2 using relations

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I would like to get data of a user and his roles but it returns an error of:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'auth_item.user_id'  in 'on clause'
>         The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblusers` LEFT JOIN `auth_item` ON `tblusers`.`id` = `auth_item`.`user_id`

I have tried:
Search model

```
$query = User::find()->joinWith('role');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
        'pagination' => ['pageSize' => $pageSize]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
```

Relationship on the user model

```
public function getRole()
{
    // User has_one Role via Role.user_id -> id
    return $this->hasOne(Role::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Relationship on the role model

```
public function getUser()
{
     return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

This is the full search:

```
public function search($params, $pageSize = 10)
{
   $query = User::find()->joinWith('role');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
        'pagination' => ['pageSize' => $pageSize]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
    die();

    // if user is not 'theCreator' ( You ), do not show him users with this role
     // if user is not 'theCreator' ( You ), do not show him users with this role
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('theCreator')) {
        $query->where(['!=', 'item_name', 'theCreator']);
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_ASC]],
        'pagination' => ['pageSize' => $pageSize]
    ]);

    // make item_name (Role) sortable
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['item_name'] = [
        'asc' => ['item_name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['item_name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'item_name', $this->item_name]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

This is the authitem model

```
<?php 
  namespace app\rbac;

  use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
  use Yii;

    class AuthItem extends ActiveRecord
    {  public static function tableName()
   { 
    return '{{%auth_item}}';
   }
   public static function getRoles()
   {
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('theCreator')) 
    {
        return static::find()->select('name')->where(['type' => 1])->all();  
    }
    else
    {
        return static::find()->select('name')
                             ->where(['type' => 1])
                             ->andWhere(['!=', 'name', 'theCreator'])
                             ->all();
    }
  }        
  }
```

THIS IS THE CODE UPDATE:
On this line

```
$query = User::find()->joinWith('role');
```

it actually relates to auth assignment as below:

```
<?php
namespace app\rbac;

  use app\models\User;
     use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
    use Yii;
     class Role extends ActiveRecord
   {
  public static function tableName()
   {
    return '{{%auth_assignment}}';
   }
   public function rules()
        {
    return [
        [['item_name'], 'required'],
        [['item_name'], 'string', 'max' => 64],
    ];
}

 public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'item_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Role'),
    ];
}


public function getUser()
{
    // Role has_many User via User.id -> user_id
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}


}
```

Why does it return that error?

Comment: Upload your full query. The error and the query you have uploaded is not matching

Comment: seems you don't have the column  user_id in your auth_item table  -- show the auth_item related  model or table schema

Comment: @scais Why authitem i would like it to use auth assignment

Comment: @scais Why authitem i would like it to use auth assignment as auth assignment has the id fields

Comment: I have posted and answer hope is useful

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default rbac models/module from yii2 could be you  are relating the wrong model/table  .. because the auth_itme model don't contain user_id column

```
/**
* This is the model class for table "auth_item".
*
* @property string $name
* @property integer $type
* @property string $description
* @property string $rule_name
* @property string $data
* @property integer $created_at
* @property integer $updated_at
```

Could be instead that you want relate the auth_assignment table which  contain relation between auth_item and user

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "auth_assignment".
 *
 * @property string $item_name
 * @property string $user_id
 * @property integer $created_at
 *
```

Comment: As I thought .. auth_item not contain user_id .. (you can also check the database table which should be called auth_item ..) auth_item only it contains the master list of names (and type) of permits .... If you want to see auth connected to each user you have to look at the model of assignments and possibly put this model in connection with auth_item and user

Comment: what i dont get is that there is an extension of authassignment relationshi p when  $query = User::find()->joinWith('role'); join with role ill update the code with the auth assignment in the role.php

Comment: Comment in three part: part1

If I correctly understand your question was related to the fact that manifested an error on a column of a table .. by verifcation you can do based on my response can clearly check that the error is due to the fact that in the associated table the model you are using the field you are trying to use does not exist .. I think this is the right answer to your question.

Comment: part 2

I also suggested that if you want to get the relationship between auh_item and user .. you should use the auth_assignment model but on how to complete this aspect I think you should use a new specific question. As it regards your latest comment can not understand it for two reasons .. the first as ever if you want to create a read query (select) the query would change the relationship with assignments ..

Comment: part 3 The second is that I do not know what extension or module are you using for the management rbac .. or what the outcome you want to achieve. because your question is related to the fact that it does not work a join clause ..